# Lasso regularization doesn't work on high dimensions?

Tags: lasso, dimensionality-reduction, high-dimensional

Please see the following in highlighted (ISLR 2nd Edition pg 265):

[image]

The last sentence (`p=2000` example) is very concerning to me. I was going to use Lasso in everyday practice to do feature selection (believe this is an accepted method of feature selection). However, to me, this sentence basically says:

"Lasso regularization is useless in high dimensional settings. It is unable to pick out the 20 important features by giving them large coefficients, and unable reduce the other 50 and 91 unimportant features respectively to essentially 0." Is this interpretation correct?

The only exception I can think of is those 70 and 111 features (respectively) in the `p=2000` experiment coincidentally did not include those 20 important features out of 2000. I don't think this is the case though, since in both the `p=20` and `p=50` examples, it is clear that all 20 important features are included in those models.

Comment: "Not useless" is too strong to be defensible, because it does not consider why someone might be using the Lasso.  If your objective is limited to finding features "truly associated with the outcome," even then the Lasso might be useful at narrowing the possibilities.  Indeed, I have found that repeating the Lasso (with different random folds for cross-validation) can uncover a useful subset of features for further examination or for designing future studies.

Comment: You have only 100 observations!  In the p = 2000 case, the Lasso appears to have successfully eliminated over 1900 irrelevant features out of 1980... based on only 100 observations!   In the p = 50 case, it appears likely to have eliminated roughly 20 of the 30 irrelevant features and identified almost all of the 20 relevant ones... based on only 100 observations!  That strikes me as remarkably good, frankly.

Comment: @jbowman Oh nice catch i definitely missed that. So correct me if im wrong, you're essentially saying that if we had lets say n = 3000 (just to have n>p), we would likely see a similar dropoff in Test MSE like we saw in the first two examples?

Comment: Yes indeed, probably with a lot fewer than 3000 actually.